# Tooltip on Image element inside RichEditableText

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, tooltip, flash-builder, image

I have the following:

```
<s:RichEditableText>        
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
             <s:p><s:a click="linkelement1_clickHandler(event);"><s:img id="ccIMG" source="{imgCls}"></s:img></s:a></s:p>
       </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

I want to display a tooltip on the img element - haven't figured this one out - ideas anyone?

thanks!

mce

Comment: oops! hit the wrong button! I've tried setting a tooltip in the init function of addressing the id ccIMG 0 tried a couple other things with no luck (can't remember right now!)

Comment: wow! Flextras has rep in top 1%! awesome!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is that the image won't dispatch regular events as other elements on the displaylist will. To be more precise, it will not dispatch MOUSE_OVER or ROLL_OVER events for you to listen for and display a tooltip.

So you'll have to listen for those events on the entire RichEditableText and do some hit-testing to detect whether the mouse is over an image or not.

Suppose you have some textflow like this:

```
<s:RichEditableText width="100%" height="100%" mouseOver="toggleTooltip()">
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
            <s:p>
                <s:span>Some text before</s:span>
                <s:img id="myImg" source="myImg.png" />
                <s:span>Some text after</s:span>
            </s:p>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>
</s:RichEditableText>
```

And you listen for mouseOver events on the entire textcomponent.

Then to test if the mouse is over your image, implement the mouseOver handler:

```
private function toggleTooltip():void {
    var graphic:DisplayObject = myImg.graphic;
    var anchor:Point = graphic.localToGlobal(new Point(0, 0));

    if (mouseX >= anchor.x && mouseX <= anchor.x + graphic.width &&
        mouseY >= anchor.y && mouseY <= anchor.y + graphic.height) 
    {
        trace('show tooltip');
    }
    else {
        trace('hide tooltip');
    }
}
```